# Using Mendeley with Lyx, only one document appears

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I'm trying to use Mendeley to do the citations in Lyx. I have a list of 10 documents, but when I want to do the citation in Lyx, only one appears. Why? I've tried inserting the documents again but nothing.
Can you help me please? 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/97512) with your code so far? This helps us to help you.

Comment: @nox https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YZUc_7iddquzEXKyfzZqciYfXfBq1egM

Comment: There is an inline code function, could you please edit your post using it, rather than posting a link? It works by adding four leading spaces  `    ` or a tab ` ` to the beginning of each line.

Comment: @nox I have a mendeley .bib document that i open with lyx. I don't use any code or I don't understand what you mean with code. I can put pictures, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to put all the documents into a folder in Mendeley or else it would only save the one I had my cursor on.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you think this is a LyX bug or a Mendeley bug, or is it natural to have to do what you needed to? If there's something to be improved, we should figure out where and let them know. By the way, welcome to tex.se!

Comment: @scottkosty i guess it's a Mendeley bug.

Comment: OK. If you report it to them and hear back, please update this question. That way anyone else who sees the same bug you do and finds this question will know the current status.